# update a region

Tags: python

Does someone know, why this simple script is not working?

```
import bpy

bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'PROPERTIES'

bpy.context.space_data.context = 'PARTICLES'

bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add()

bpy.ops.particle.new()

bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
```

It works every SECOND time and then it works always until I quit blender. 
Next time it works every second time again.

I'm thankful for help :) Try to get it since about a year...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use operators for that. Add the particle system as a modifier instead:

```
import bpy

particles = bpy.context.object.modifiers.new("Some name", 'PARTICLE_SYSTEM')
# if you need to adjust it:
particles.particle_system.settings.count = 15
```

In case you wonder how you are supposed to know how to access the different settings - just type `particles = bpy.context.object.modifiers.new("Some name", 'PARTICLE_SYSTEM')` in the Python console and then you can use autocomplete function(ctrl+space after `particles.particle_system.settings.`) to find out what is available:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)  My big Problem is not the particle-System. I knew the way with the Modifier already. The Problem are the particle-SETTINGS. I couldn't find a way to ad the particle-settings in another way then with the "ops".

Comment: And now, I found out that your way is much better than the idea I had before. Thank you for your help!